# Put a standard string on a label

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

I'm currently trying to make a label showing different text for each user, to have a standard text before this label but not inside the cell on the .xib file.

What i've done until know is this

```
import UIKit

class profileViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet var lblUsersname: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var lblUserspoints: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var imgViewUserAvatar: UIImageView!

var profileJson : [String:AnyObject] = [ : ]
var userid = ""
var usersname = ""
var userspoints = ""
var usersavatar = ""
var pointtxt = "Points: "

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    if let usersid = defaults.stringForKey("usersId") {
        userid = usersid
        fetchDatas()
        lblUsersname.text = usersname
        lblUserspoints.text = userspoints
    }else{
        print("Error")
    }

    if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: usersavatar) {
        downloadImage(checkedUrl)
    }

}

func fetchDatas(){

    let urlara = NSLocalizedString("profileRequest", comment: "")
    let loginRequest = receiveData(data1: "id=\(userid)", url1: NSURL(string: urlara)!)
    profileJson = loginRequest.fetchData()

    if let locationsArray = profileJson["profile"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        for locationDictionary in locationsArray {
            if let name = locationDictionary["name"] as? String {
                usersname = name
            }
            if let points = locationDictionary["points"] as? String {
                userspoints = points
            }
            if let avatar = locationDictionary["avatar"] as? String {
                usersavatar = avatar
            }

        }
    }

}
```

So now it's show only the number of the points
And i'm trying to make it show

```
Points: lblUserpoints
```

Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

After some tryings i find it out. changed the line

```
lblUserspoints.text = userspoints
```

to this

```
lblUserpoints.text = String(pointtxt) + userpoints
```

And i had the desired output which was

```
Points: 2910
```